# Propel select one column from a table

Tags: mysql, database, orm, propel

I'm using Propel two, I want to be able to select the value of one column in a given table, the equivalent raw SQL query looks like this:

```
select author_id from book_authors WHERE book_id = 111;
```

If I write

```
BookAuthorsQuery::create()->findByAuthorId(111);
```

I will get an array objects containing all the fields that the table has, but i just one an array containing the values of my selected column.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
BookAuthorsQuery::create()->select(array('author_id'))->findByBookId(111);
```

the `->select(array('author_id'))` in the propel query gives propel an array of fields you would like to select from your table.

Comment: Hey there. Please consider explaining in words what this is doing and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Hi @FélixGagnon-Grenier, please have a look at this section of the documentation: http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html#getting-columns-instead-of-objects

Comment: you can add multiple columns to the array like this:

->select(array('id', 'fname', 'lname', 'fullname'))

Answer (score 0):

this get the value! on

```
$authorId = BookAuthorsQuery::create()->select(['author_id'])->findOneByAuthorId(111);
```